# creating a DataFrame using a list of tuples; pandas does not recognize number of columns

Tags: python, pandas

the following is a part of the dataset I have:

```
table_list = [('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tbl_Constants', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tbl_Diamand_auth', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tbl_import_tracking', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tbl_MNCM_BH_Insurance_Lookup', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tbl_static_views', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tblAUDIT', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tblCallTimeBest_LookUp', 'TABLE', None),
 ('Psych_CMS_Staging', 'dbo', 'tblCMS', 'TABLE', None)]
```

I want to create a data frame, this is my code:

```
tables_list =pd.DataFrame(table_list , #columns = list('abcde'))
```

But it has the following error:

```
"Shape of passed values is (533, 1), indices imply (533, 5)"
```

Comment: I don't get any error with your code

Comment: works on my system.

Comment: yea worked fine for me too

Comment: same there. what version of python, pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using anaconda version with python version 3.7

Comment: Carefully check what you post is exactly same object as in current environment. Always run code in an empty Python environment before posting on SO so code is reproducible.

Comment: I am voting to close this issue because there is not a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The question can be edited to provide additional details, that make the error reproducible.